# Visual studio 2017 Imported project was not found .Also tried to find"Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" in the fallback search path

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**Xamarin.Android project no working but Xamarin.iOS works properly**

> /Users/Projects/HelloImage/HelloImage.Android/HelloImage.Android.csproj(10,10): Error MSB4226: The imported project "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/" and "/Volumes/DATA/APPS/Visual Studio(old).app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild" . These search paths are defined in "/Users/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/7.0/MSBuild/3075_1/MonoDevelop.MSBuildBuilder.exe.config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths. (MSB4226) (HelloImage.Android)

Comment: Please add more details to your question

Comment: thanks, G.hakim for a quick response. When I try to Debug the My Xamarin Forms project in Android, then I will get that's the error. I faced the same error in every new project, but the iOS part works properly

Comment: did you try restarting vs?

Comment: Yeah, Sir, Me restarts Visual Studio many times but the error remains as same.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: That is error message:-------Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths. (MSB4226), me also describe in the question body.

Comment: check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/285c23d6-0836-4bf1-a109-5e1df5a85335/confirm-that-the-path-in-the-ltimportgt-declaration-is-correct-and-that-the-file-exists-on-disk?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me when I install the VS for MAC and run an existing Xamarin forms project.

The issue was that Xamarin Android was not installed properly. you can try to create a new Xaamrin form application and you'll see that the Android under Target Platforms was Greyed Out.

To resolve this issue, I've installed it again using Visual Studio installer.

Comment: Ahmed El-Araby,Actaully I ignored some importants Updates of Visual Studio components ,when I updates these components then my Visual studio works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Actaully, I ignored some importants Updates of Visual Studio components ,when I updates these components then my Visual studio works perfectly.So don't ignore components update of VS.